# Profile form submit error page displays duplicate data entry fields

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, profile, error-page

I’ve used a profile on a Wordpress page on our website to gather constituent demographic info, with required fields set at the profile level.  If you’re on this page as a visitor to the website and fail to fill in a required field, on Submit you’ll get the expected error message(s) and page re-displayed with the unfilled required fields flagged, BUT you also see ALL the select-type fields duplicated!  Below’s a link to the page - just click submit without filling anything in and you’ll see what I mean.  This happens both on a computer and mobile phone browser.

Can anyone give me some clues as to what’s going on, what’s causing these fields to be duplicated on re-display?  Thanks for any help you can give me.

https://californianational.party/demo-survey-2019/

WordPress 4.9.10 running Ascend Child theme
Page Builder by SiteOrigin 2.10.5
CiviCRM 4.7.29

Comment: I tried to address this by taking Page Builder out of the picture.  I created a version of the page just using the normal WP editor but now it's even worse - now when you first view the page those select-type fields are all duplicated right off the bat!  Here's the link to that page: <https://californianational.party/demogr-census-2019v2/>

Comment: You probably need to address the Javascript error before you can narrow this down.

Comment: I'll have to find someone to help me with that.  In the meantime since I need to have this go live I changed ALL fields to be non-required (and added reCaptcha) so as not to trigger the error page.  Terrible for data integrity but there you go.  If anyone still wants to see the problem use the link in my 1st comment - I'd appreciate any insights.